# Can "Time" exist alone as one of the datetime class in R or must it become a character?

Tags: r, datetime

I know there are 8 million questions on datetimes, but I have to ask this because I think I'm going insane (as one does). I also think people persistently try to accomplish this task without realizing it cannot be done (as one originally intends at least, there are hacks to substitute the same year and month as dummy values).

Why is it so difficult to separate the time out of a "POSIXct" "POSIXt" class vector??

**I have some dates:**

```
# These seem fine to me... So its not the "EDT"
some_datetimes <- as.POSIXct(c("1961-07-16 05:00:00 EDT", "1961-07-16 05:00:00 EDT", "1961-07-16 17:00:00 EDT"))
class(some_datetimes)

some_datetimes <- as.POSIXct(c("1961-07-16 05:00:00", "1961-07-16 05:00:00", "1961-07-16 17:00:00"))
class(some_datetimes)
```

**I want the times, but as a class that remembers its a time (for plotting/modeling):**

```
# Can we pull the time?:
strptime(some_datetimes, format = "%H:%M:%S") # Returns NA
strptime(some_datetimes, format = "%T")       # Returns NA
strftime(some_datetimes, format = "%H:%M:%S") # Returns Character
strftime(some_datetimes, format = "%T")       # Returns Character
format(some_datetimes, format = "%H:%M:%S")   # Returns a character value
format(some_datetimes, format = "%T")         # Returns a character value
```

**Can time exist on its own and still be POSIXct?**

If not, why would we do this to ourselves?

Comment: You might try `hms::as_hms(some_datetimes)`. Or you could restate your POSIXct with the same date, like `library(lubridate); ymd_hms(paste("2024-01-01", format(some_datetimes, format = "%H:%M:%S")))`

Comment: A POSIXct object is a POSIXct object. Without the date element, it can no longer be treated as such by the methods defined fot it. There are existing time-only classes in extension packages, and it is easy enough to create an S3 class yourself if you want something different. To me, the question should be "why is there no time-only class in base R?". That is a question that we can't really answer, as it comes down to what the R core team believe is important enough to include in base R.